# The sentence 'I use this way' sounds weird?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, linguistics

In the dictionary the word 'way' is regarded as a noun but is most of the time used as an adverb.

For example, I cook the meat in this way or this is the way I cook the meat

So, here is my question. If I say, 'I use this way in making cocktails', does this sound weird?

There might be many ways to make cocktails and I use this way.

'I' is a pronoun, 'use' is a verb, 'this way' could be a noun, which is a perfect sentence?

Answer (score 2):

We would say 'I use this way *of* making cocktails'.

It's *do it in this way* but *the way of doing it.*